# Basic integral with chain rule

Tags: integration

What is the the mathematical correct way to show that
$$\int \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dt} dt=\int \frac{1}{y} dy$$
In my tutorial we just cancelled the $dt$, but is this really correct?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\mathrm{d}y$ in the last integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just canceling the $dt$ isn't technically correct, even if it does work in this case. The formal way to do the substitution is using the chain rule.

First define the antiderivative $$F(y) = \int \frac{1}{y} dy$$ 
so that $F^\prime(y) = \frac{1}{y}$. Then, viewing $y$ as a function of $t$, by the chain rule we get that $$\frac{d}{dt} F(y(t)) = F^\prime(y(t))y^\prime(t) = \frac{1}{y(t)} \frac{dy}{dt}$$ implying that $$F(y(t)) = \int \frac{1}{y(t)}\frac{dy}{dt}dt$$

Another technical consideration is that $F(y)$ is formally a function of $y$ and $F(y(t))$ is formally a function of $t$, but replacing $y$ with $y(t)$ in $F(y) = \int \frac{1}{y} dy$ lets us say that

$$\int \frac{1}{y(t)} \frac{dy}{dt} dt = \int \frac{1}{y} dy \bigg\rvert_{y = y(t)}$$